# HtmlUnit could not automate login Website

Tags: java, passwords, webclient, htmlunit

Hello I'm new to HtmlUnit, I have a problem on coding for this one. I couldn't login according to this code did I miss something of what? here is my code for example I wan't to login of that URL. Please check my code I'm debugging this long time. Thank you. I want to Unit test if it can download the excel file after logging in. then write it to the stream. the URL is live website. could you help me please. before you can download the file is you need to login that's what I'm working now but could not login.

```
    String url = "https://www.frw.co.uk/login";
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    try {

        HtmlPage login = webClient.getPage(url);//button.click();

        final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) login.getElementById("loginForm");

        form.getInputByName("j_username").setValueAttribute("example@hotmail.com");
        form.getInputByName("j_password").setValueAttribute("examplePassword");

        HtmlPage reslogin = form.getInputByValue("Login").click();

        final HtmlPage downloadPage = reslogin.getAnchorByText("Download Wine List").click();

        final HtmlPage p = downloadPage.getPage();


        WebResponse response2 = p.getWebResponse();
        InputStream is = response2.getContentAsStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileTarget));

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
```

Comment: Ok I haven't notice it sorry for this and thanks for the heads up! :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to add automatic redirection with cookieManager

```
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
```

Comment: still could not login. I tried to output the page asText still on the login page.